Assigning the input from a HTML form as a variable
I am trying to code a URL shortener website and I have ran into a problem where I am getting 'Error' when trying to shorten my URL. It worked and gave a test URL when there was a link in the 'long_url' variable on my URL Shortener.py but when I tried changing it to get the input from the HTML form, it has stopped working. Does anyone know how to correctly assign an input from an HTML form to a python variable. I will attach my files.
app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', long_url='long_url')
@app.route('/')
def getvalue():
    long_url = request.form['long_url']
    return long_url

@app.route('/run-script', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def run_script():
    script_path = 'URL Shortener.py'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            result = subprocess.check_output(['python', script_path], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
            return result
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            return str(e.stderr)
    return "Invalid request method"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)

URL Shortener.py
import requests

url = 'http://tinurl.com/api-create.php?url=' <-- This is meant to say tinyurl but stack overflow will not allow me to post it with the link as it thinks it is malicious.

long_url = 'long_url'

response = requests.get(url+long_url)
short_url = response.text

print(short_url)

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>URL Shortener</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>URL Shortener - Project</h1>
    <h2>Hello, welcome to my URL shortener. Check it out and make use of it as and when you need to. Thanks for checking it out!</h2>
    <label for="long_url">Enter Long URL Here:</label>
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('run_script') }}">
        <input type="text" id="long_url" name="long_url"> <!-- Added name attribute to the input field -->
        <button type="submit">Shorten URL</button>
    </form>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>


I tried editing the long_url variable in app.py to an example long_url which gave the example short_url but it will not change depending on the input in the input box as the long_url is determined already. I also tried def getvalue(): which can be seen in app.py but that did not work either. Any suggestions would be great!

You are not passing the HTML form value to your script.  You're just encoding the string "long_url".  You never even fetch that value from your request object.  Also, it is poor practice to put spaces in your script file names.  It's not technically invalid, but it will cause you pain in the future.

As a side note, it's rather unethical to call this "my URL shortener", when you are simply usurping the services of another company.

Why not make URL Shortener.py a module you can import with a function that you call, rather than calling it as a subprocess?

You never call getvalue(). Also, why do you have it in @app.route('/')?

You need to fetch the long URL from your form and pass it as a parameter to your script.
@app.route('/run-script', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def run_script():
    script_path = 'URL Shortener.py'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            long_url = request.form['long_url']
            result = subprocess.check_output(['python', script_path, long_url], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
            return result
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            return str(e.stderr)
    return "Invalid request method"

Then URLShortener.py is:
import sys
import requests

url = 'http://tinurl.com/api-create.php?url='

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print( "Must provide the long URL as a parameter." )
    exit(0)

long_url = sys.argv[1]
response = requests.get(url+long_url)
short_url = response.text

print(short_url)

